# Material UI - React Js - Datepicker selecting next date

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material ui datepicker -

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DatePicker value={selectedDate} onChange={date=>handleDateChange(date)} 
                  shouldDisableDate={disableWeekends} />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>

function disableWeekneds(date){
  let datesToDisabled=['2021-10-18','2021-10-20']
  const dateInt = [
   datesToDisabled[0],
datesToDisabled[1]
];
let isToDisabled=dateInt.includes(date.toISOString().split('T')[0])

return date.getDay()==6 || date.getDay()==0 || isToDisabled;
}
```

Here in disable weekends function I am disabling weekends + custom dates.
When I open calender , I see disabled dates to be - 19th Oct and 20th Oct.

How can I resolve this?
I tried with - parseISO , but no use.

Comment: Could you share your code on sandbox please

Comment: I believe all logic are [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/1fd3387425b97c6b3882f0e1d9c3e73a97a1507a/packages/mui-lab/src/internal/pickers/date-utils.ts#L15) in findClosestEnabledDate. In example below version are 5.0.0, but same with datePicker 4.0.0. As you can see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicdatepicker-material-demo-forked-oy6xw?file=/demo.js) it just takes and moves one day forward all days you selected.